# Primary key check in django

Tags: django, django-models, primary-key, django-views

I have this custom primary key in a model:

```
class Personal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True,null=True)
```

Now the thing i m not getting is, how can i create my view so that no duplicate record is entered? I searched this over online, but could find any technique to get the view created.

here is the code for views

```
def uregister(request):
    errors = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.POST.get('txtName', ''):
            errors.append('Enter a Name.')
        if not errors:
            n = request.POST['txtName']
            e = request.POST['txtEmail']
            try:
                per_job = Personal(name=n, email=e)
                per_job.save()
            except IntegrityError:
                return render_to_response('gharnivas/register.html', {'exists': true}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return render_to_response('register.html', {'errors': errors}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How can i tel the user that, the name already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Catch the inevitable exception](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html) upon saving, and tell them.

Comment: I have updated the views.py as shown in the question. But now the problem is, the data is overwritten not showing any exception of primary key.!! This is even the same at the shell level object creation. The `primary_key` is not helping it to make unique. :(

Comment: Right. That's because the primary key will not make it unique. If you put in a value that has the same primary key then it will replace the existing record. Go back to the automatic primary key, and make the field just `unique` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
per_job.save(force_insert=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is Form and Form Validation:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#customizing-the-form-template

Define a PersonalForm class, move your validation checks in form field definitions or clean*() methods, then show error fields from form in template.

Django book link for form processing:

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07/

Comment: I din't ask the form submission or usage. please refer my question. It is about, how can i check the primary key constraint !!

Comment: Ok..got confused by "view creation" and "telling the user".

Comment: Anyway, if you had a PersonalForm around Personal model, it should honor primary_key=True constraint present in model and should fill in error fields in Form instance on violation. I think Form is the right way for this, which you do not seem to be using.