# Primary key and unique key in django

Tags: django, primary-key, unique-key

I had a custom primary key that need to be set up on a particular data in a model.

This was not enough, as an attempt to insert a duplicate number succeeded. So now when i replace `primary_key=True` to `unique=True` it works properly and rejects duplicate numbers!!. But according this [document](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key) (**which uses fields**).

`primary_key=True` implies `null=False`
and `unique=True.`

> Which makes me confused as in why does
>   it accept the value in the first place
>   with having an inbuilt `unique=True` ?

Thank you.

**Updated statement:**

```
   personName = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=20)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use an [`AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#s-autofield) with `primary_key` instead.

**Edit:**

If you don't use an `AutoField`, you'll have to manually calculate/set the value for the primary key field. This is rather cumbersome. Is there a reason you *need* `ReportNumber` to the primary key? You could still have a unique report number on which you can query for reports, as well as an auto-incrementing integer primary key.

**Edit 2:**

When you say duplicate primary key values are allowed, you indicate that what's happening is that an existing record with the same primary key is updated -- there aren't actually two objects with the same primary key in the database (which can't happen). The issue is in the way Django's ORM layer chooses to do an `UPDATE` (modify an existing DB record) vs. an `INSERT INTO` (create a new DB record). Check out this line from `django.db.models.base.Model.save_base()`:

```
if (force_update or (not force_insert and
        manager.using(using).filter(pk=pk_val).exists())):
    # It does already exist, so do an UPDATE.
```

Particularly, this snippet of code:

```
manager.using(using).filter(pk=pk_val).exists()
```

This says: "If a record with the same primary key as this `Model` exists in the database, then do an update." So if you re-use a primary key, Django assumes you are doing an update, and thus doesn't raise an exception or error.

---

I think the best idea is to let Django generate a primary key for you, and then have a separate field (`CharField` or whatever) that has the `unique` constraint.

Comment: @mipadi : My requirements are with respect to have it set manually. I understand your concern for `AutoFiled`. But again, your solution would solve the query where i want it to be AutoField. The thing i wanted is a manual entry from registrar for that. Again even if I use **CharFiled** I would get the original field replaced with the new `CharField` record. And if you notice the last part of my question, I have asked a doubt as in why it din't work? Why it replaces even when it has default `unique=True` in `primary_key` ?

Comment: @Nagaraj Tantri: Right. I'm asking why the report number specifically has to be the primary key. You can have a unique, manually-entered report number (you can even index that to make queries faster), as well as a separate, auto-generated ID number (that is also the primary key).

Comment: Also, what database backend are you using?

Comment: @mipadi : I ougth had to keep record number as per admin wanted it to be with integer. I use Sqlite3 . As i have another similar kinda problem with `personName=models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=20)` I thought posting the question with only one field rather than two similar queries.

Comment: And also, For the actual question, I am not getting any answer, so ill again update the question with `CharField`. Its even problem with the `CharField`.

Comment: @Nagaraj Tantri: When you re-use a primary key, does it actually save both objects, so there are two objects with the same primary key (i.e., `ReportNumber`)?

Comment: @mipadi: No, It rewrites the existing record. For example, with same name as John if i enter with existing record it over writes it with new record. If you can see the second comment in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034574/primary-key-check-in-django#answers-header

Comment: @Nagaraj Tantri: I think that's just how the SQL standard, or at least SQLite, works.

Comment: @mipadi : Its Sqlite3's problem or every other SQL tat Django supports?

Comment: @Nagaraj Tantri: The same behavior occurs when using MySQL. I imagine it's the same for all database backends. I believe the issue is in the way Django detects whether to do an `INSERT INTO` or an `UPDATE` in its ORM layer. If you're creating an object with the same primary key as a record in the database, I imagine Django assumes you're doing an `UPDATE`.

Comment: @mipadi. : If you are sure of it, could u answer it by updating ur answer?