# Django not assigning any primary key

Tags: python, django

When saving my table Django does not seem to be assigning any primary key? I'm I missing something?

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    campaignid = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, db_column='campaignID')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=105)
    active = HibernateBooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    modified = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    companyid = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, db_column='companyID', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'campaign'


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: No. Wipe the table, resync, and dump the schema.

Comment: Can you really have a charfield as primary key?

Comment: my tables are already pre-populated using Hibernate I cannot drop the table as they contain data from another app.

Comment: Ok, but even if it is valid, how would Django know how to populate it?  This question contains some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039443/primary-key-and-unique-key-in-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok as my model was generated from an existing table using guid I had to keep it as CharField adding this seemed to work:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.campaignid:
            self.campaignid = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()
        super(Campaign, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```